# Improving input impedance at higher frequencies for multi-stage MOSFET amplifier

Tags: transistors, mosfet, amplifier, multisim

I am trying to design a three-stage amplifier and I currently have two common source amplifiers and a buffer, to help drive a small 8 ohm load. However, as my frequency increases, my input impedance drastically decreases. I require at least 200k Ohm input impedance, but I can't seem to achieve this. I don't understand why the input impedance is not simply R1||R2. I am looking for tips to help improve my input impedance.

[image: Three-stage Amp]

Comment: At what frequency do you need 200kohm input impedance? We don't know if "higher" means 200 Hz or 200 MHz to you.

Comment: Short answer,  you probably need input transistors with lower gate capacitance, or to re- think your requirements.

Comment: Why is M1 totally in parallel with M3? Ditto the other two?

Comment: 200kohm input resistance for a 10kHz input signal. Unfortunately, these are the only available transistors I have to work with. I have no solution for any parasitic capacitance. @ThePhoton

Comment: Parallel transistors to double transconductance @Andyaka